# Handling with variable in function with swift

Tags: swift, variables, nsurl, func, fileserver

Please remember that I'm still an absolute beginner. I have still problems with C- and Swift-Code. Now I want to read a textfile from a file-Server. It works fine. Unfortunately I can't manage to transfer the data from the function to my viewdidload-controller.
I tried this:

```
func datenbankLaden() -> String {

    // Download der Datendatei
    var loadedString = ""

    var myURL: NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://www.*myfileserver*.de/images/uploads/data.txt")!
    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            // Success
            let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            println("Success: \(statusCode)")
            loadedString = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding) as! String
            return loadedString
        }
        else {
            // Failure
            println("Faulure: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    })
    task.resume()
    println(task)
}
```

I know that this "return loadedString" refers to the "`let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest`-Function. But how can I fix it. I tried to set a variable in the class. Instead of "`return loadedString`" I tried "`newString (*declared in the class*) == loadedString`". This dosen't work either.

And just one more thing ...
How can I read the content in www.*myfileserver*.de/uploads/ to find textfiles beginning with "Data... .txt"

Comment: What do you plan on doing with this string in `viewDidLoad`? Display it somehow in a UI element?

Comment: I want to split the string into parts and compare them with a CoreData-Database to add new data. This procedure should be done in another function.

Comment: I agree. But it doesn't sound like you need to do it in `viewDidLoad`. Could you just call your other function from the `completionHandler` of your `task`?

Comment: I thought it might a bit clearer to use two functions. Nevertheless it might be possible to start a function in the completionHandler to manage the data. Instead of "return loadedString" I could start a function e.g. "func workWithData (String)" and call it in the completionHandler by "workWithData(loadedString)".

Comment: That is the right idea!